# generating pdf using sinatra and pdf. pdf displays odd in browser

Tags: sinatra, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I am using pdfkit to generate a pdf via the following code:

```
get "/:lang/:course/:project/protected/:project.pdf" do
    PDFKit.configure do |config|
    config.wkhtmltopdf = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
    config.default_options = {
      :page_size => 'A3',
      # :load_error_handling => 'skip',
      # :load_media_error_handling => "ignore",
      # :debug_javascript => true,
      # :javascript_delay => "300",
      :print_media_type => true,
      :margin_top => "8mm",
      :margin_bottom => "5mm",
      :footer_spacing => "-8",
     }
   end 
    kit = PDFKit.new("http://localhost:4000/#{params[:lang]}/#{params[:course]}/#{params[:project]}/")
    kit.to_pdf
```

I can see in my puma logs that it is generating the pdf, however when it loads the page I see the following:

[image]

It looks like its trying to render the pdf but for reasons unknown to me it displays it like that. Iv tested this in both Chrome & Firefox.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the get request I needed to add the following code:

`headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'`